# Insert missing natural numbers in a vector

Tags: r, vector

I have a data frame column

```
df$col1=(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,...,500000)
```

and a vector

```
vc<-c(1,2,4,5,7,8,10,...,499999)
```

If i compare the two vectors the second vector has some missing values how i can insert in the missing values' places 0s e.g the second vector i want to be

```
vc<-c(1,2,0,4,5,0,7,8,9,10,...,499999,0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using the larger vector containing all values as a template, and then assign zero to any value which does *not* match to the second smaller vector:

```
v_out <- df$col1
v_out[!(v_out %in% vc)] <- 0
v_out

[1]  1  2  0  4  5  0  7  8  0 10
```

**Data**

```
df$col1 <- c(1:10)
vc <- c(1,2,4,5,7,8,10)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `match` and `replace` (thanks to @RonakShah)

Input

```
vc <- c(1,2,4,5,7,8,10)
x <- 1:15
```

Result

```
out <- replace(tmp <- vc[match(x, vc)], is.na(tmp), 0L)
out
# [1]  1  2  0  4  5  0  7  8  0 10  0  0  0  0  0
```

Comment: I had no idea you could save an object inside `replace` and then use it at *condition* argument.

Answer (score 1):

A more cryptic, but maybe faster one-liner alternative (using Tim's data):

```
`[<-`(numeric(max(df$col1)),vc,vc)
#[1]  1  2  0  4  5  0  7  8  0 10
```

Comment: assuming `col1` always starts from 1 ?